# REST URI design for tree structures

Tags: rest, tree, uri

There is a lot of discussions out there about REST URI design, but none replied precisely to my question.

Let's say I have some lists that contains tasks and / or other lists (list = node and task = leaf).

We can have something like

```
/lists/{id_list1}/lists/{id_list2}/lists/{id_list3}/tasks/{id_task1}
```

or maybe a shorter version :

```
/lists/{id_list1}/{id_list2}/{id_list3}/{id_task1}
```

But what about really deep trees ?

I was also thinking about the parent/child relation which could be translated like

```
/lists/{id_list_parent}/{id_list_or_task_child}
```

but I feel like something's missing...

What would be a smart design for REST URI trees ?

EDIT

Sorry for my late answer !

So I think I was mixing 2 needs : API URIs and browser URIs.

Here's how I see things :

On the API side, I'll have only those URIs for both write and read methods (the '/id' at the end is not required, for create for instance) :

```
/lists/id
/tasks/id
```

On my browser however, I'll have something like this :

```
/lists/id/lists/id/tasks/
```

Only the first part (/lists/id) will be interpreted by the server, the second part (lists/id/tasks/) will be used by my client side javascript to find the tasks of the sublist of the list received from the server.

What do you think of this approach, does something feel wrong in it ?

Comment: Have a look at the url on Git Hub https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/docs/templates folders are nodes and files are leafs. I think it works well!

Comment: URI is not part of the REST API. REST is about content, not URIs. This should let you free to choose one URI organisation, and change it later on. Anyway : why do you need /lists/{id_list1}/lists/{id_list2}/lists/{id_list3}/tasks/{id_task1}? This seem to lead to task with id 3, so couldn't this be reduced to /lists/{id_list3}/tasks to have the list of tasks, and /tasks/{id_task1} for the task within the list?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my question was not exact, see my edit above.

Answer (score 13):

Is there any need to represent the tree via the URIs? When they can simply be references to the nodes themselves and the relationships are modeled via links in the hypermedia type.

Other than that, I think something like:

```
/lists/{nodeId}/children
```

and it can return a list of the direct children to the parent.

You can also do something like:

```
/lists/{nodeId}/children?depth=3
```

and return the next three levels of the tree in your result.

```
/lists/{nodeId}/children?depth=infinite
```

can return the entire branch from that node.

Answer (score 0):

Using the URI to enforce this constraint doesn't seem correct. I would accept a PUT request that has some kind of payload (JSON, XML, etc.).

`PUT /tasklist`

```
lists: [{
   id: 1234,
   id: 12345,
   tasks: [{
      id: foo,
      id: bar,
      id: baz
   }]
}]
```

The URL seems to indicate that you are trying to do too much here (IMHO). Typically, you would be interacting with a single resource, while your use case implies that you are operating on several contextually tiered resources at one time.